# Problem regarding mail content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am sending mail to the customers. And the format is like this:

> Name: abc. Company:ccc. Address: sde.

So the mail is coming out in continuous format which I don't want.

I want it in this format:

> Name: abc.
>
> Company:ccc.
>
> Address: sde.

I'm currently using `string.format` to populate each of the values and later on replacing '`.`' with '`\n`'.
However, it looks like that is not working.
Any suggestions on how to make it look like this?

Answer (score 4):

Use [BodyFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.bodyformat.aspx) property to format your mails as HTML format, and use <br /> for the line breaks.

```
MailMessage myMail = new MailMessage();
myMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
myMail.Body = "Name: abc.<br />";
myMail.Body += "Company:ccc.<br />";
myMail.Body += "Address: sde.<br />";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Environment.NewLine

Comment: I tried replacing char . with environemnt.newline  and it gave me error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "\n\r"?

Is the body set to be plain text or html?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a long string, I recommend you use StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(string1);
sb.AppendLine(string2):
sb.AppendLine(""); //empty line
mailMessage.Body = sb.ToString();
```

Edit:  I use this to send our text only emails and it works on non-HTML emails.

Answer (score 0):

@Canavar's answer is good, but not all mail clients support html and even those that do may have it turned off for security purposes.

As an alternative, I would say use MailFormat.Text and use the System.Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 0):

If HTML format is ok, you could just insert

```
<br>
```

If not, and you are using outlook to view the message, try one of these two:

1. Use \n\n
2. Keep your period so that the line ends with .\n

I know this seems odd, but it may make outlook happy.